Expressing a piecewise function as a Single Expression
I made this piecewise function to determine the nearest perfect square to x (start at $f(x,1))$.
$$
f(x, y)=\begin{cases} 
      y & |x-y^2|\le|x-(y+1)^2| \\
      f(x, (y+1)) & |x-y^2|>|x-(y+1)^2| \\
   \end{cases}
$$
My question is can this function be changed to a single expression, or is there at least a way to make it so the function doesn't repeat.

Unlike programming, in mathematics you can't define a function with itself. What you actually have is a function
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{cccl}
f: &D_1 &\to& \mathbb{R}\\
&(x,y)&\mapsto&f(x,y)=y
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
where $D_1=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:|x-y^2|\leq |x-(x+1)^2|\}$.
We can then define a function
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{cccl}
k: &\mathbb{R}^2 &\to& \mathbb{Z}^+_0\\
&(x,y)&\mapsto&k(x,y)=r
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
where $r$ is the least non negative integer such that $(x,y+r)\in D_1$.
If $(x,y)\in D_1$, then $r=0$.
An the last function which that one that you initially wanted
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{cccl}
g: &\mathbb{R}^2 &\to& \mathbb{R}\\
&(x,y)&\mapsto&g(x,y)= (f\circ k) (x,y)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
Naturally, you need to prove that the function $k$ is well defined but I leave that to you.
I think this solves all your questions.
